# How to adjust position of 'ToolTip' so it's next to my <label>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a little feature to my website, where the user can hover over a question mark before inserting input where the question mark will display more info about what the question is asking. This is what i'm doing so far, but it's displaying the little Tool Tip feature on it's own separate line (which i know is because of the  tags), but I want the Label and the little question mark to be next to each other.

```
<div>
     <label htmlFor="dropdown"> Table Name: </label>
     <div className="help-tip">
      <p> More info about what this is asking for exactly.</p>
     </div>
     <input
     className='input'
     value={this.state.selectedSchema.value}
     onChange={(event) => this.setState({ selectedTableName: 
     event.target.value })
     }>
     </input>
</div>

CSS: 
.help-tip{
  top: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #0095d9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 21px;
  cursor: default;
  margin-left: 320px;
}

.help-tip:before{
  content:'?';
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#fff;
}

.help-tip:hover p{
  display:block;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;

  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
  animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.help-tip p{    /* The tooltip */
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #0095d9;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  right: -4px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
.help-tip label{
  display:block; 
  width: 300px; 
  height: 300; 
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 300px;
}

.help-tip p:before{ /* The pointer of the tooltip */
  content: '';
  width:0;
  height: 0;
  border:6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color:#0095d9;
  right:10px;
  top:-12px;
}

.help-tip p:after{ /* Prevents the tooltip from being hidden */
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  content:'';
  top:-40px;
  left:0;
}
```

ToolTip HTML & CSS credit goes to: https://tutorialzine.com/2014/07/css-inline-help-tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out I used a container to use flex box on the label and the ? element also i changed the left margin of the ? element so its only 5 px away from your label. Last thing I changed was the z-index on the p element so it would be in front of the input element (this needs a position relative to work).

only showing the changed code.

html:

```
<div class="input-label-container">
 <label htmlFor="dropdown"> Table Name: </label>
 <div class="help-tip">
    <p>More info about what this is asking for exactly.</p> 
 </div>
</div>
<input/>
```

css:

```
.input-label-container {
  display: flex;    <-
}

.help-tip {
  top: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #0095d9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 21px;
  cursor: default;
  margin-left: 5px;  <-
}

.help-tip p {    /* The tooltip */
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #0095d9;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  right: -4px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  position: relative;  <-
  z-index: 999;        <-
}
```

Comment: my pleasure. have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
<div>
      <div className="full-width">
        <div className="float-left">
        <label htmlFor="dropdown"> Table Name: </label>
        </div>

        <div className="help-tip">
          <p> More info about what this is asking for exactly.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input
            className="input"
            value="Testing"
            onChange={event =>
              this.setState({ selectedTableName: event.target.value })
            }
          />

    </div>
```

CSS would be

```
.help-tip {
  top: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #0095d9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 21px;
  cursor: default;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.help-tip:before {
  content: "?";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.help-tip:hover p {
  display: block;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;

  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
  animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.help-tip p {
  /* The tooltip */
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #0095d9;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  right: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  top: -5px;
  left: 140px;
  position: absolute;
}
.help-tip label {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 300px;
}

.help-tip p:before {
  /* The pointer of the tooltip */
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #0095d9;
  right: 10px;
  top: -12px;
}

.help-tip p:after {
  /* Prevents the tooltip from being hidden */
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  content: "";
  top: -40px;
  left: 0;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}

.float-left {
  max-width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply. This didn't work for me, but I appreciate it.